# What is the legal framework regarding letting domestic cats out in Los Angeles, CA?

Tags: cats, outdoor

We are about to move from London (UK) to Los Angeles, CA, with our two cats and I was looking at information regarding domestic outdoor cats in LA.

First of all, I appreciate that the American consensus seems to be (from what I have gathered reading online so far) that one shouldn’t let domestic cats go outside because of a number of risks. I’m not looking at debating over this. However, the custom in the UK is quite the opposite: cats are *expected* to have unrestricted access to outdoor areas and some rescues won’t even let you adopt a cat if you can’t provide it. Again, not trying to debate over what’s better or worse, but my cats are used to having unrestricted access to the outdoors and we would like to keep this if possible.

This is why we are keen to understand the legal framework around domestic cats that go outdoors: is it allowed at all? Do they need some kind of identification? Do they require collars? They are both neutered and microchipped and don’t wear collars (again, local custom, cats over here rarely have collars).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you want to try law.SE instead? I am not sure, if you will find a good quality answer here...

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try that.

Comment: This is generally a matter of local law in that municipality. Ask their animal control office, or ask a local veterinarian.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about local law, not the pets themselves

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/97542/what-is-the-legal-framework-regarding-letting-domestic-cats-out-in-los-angeles